# Angular 4 - Detect connectivity issue with http request

Tags: node.js, angular, xmlhttprequest

I am facing an issue that I don't know how to solve.
I am developing a small web app in **Angular 4**. In that application, I make http request to an api I developed in **Node.js - Express** hosted in our company network.

My problem is that most of the time those calls to the api work perfectly fine. I got no problem in my dev environment, at my home, and in some of our customers networks. But in some networks, the http request does not perform.

I know that because I register every call in the api, and in those cases I do not even detect the call. In Chrome, I even get a 404 error.
Furthermore, I installed **Postman** on a customer's computer, and still no response.
I assume it is a network policy which inteferes with the api calls, but I do not know what I am looking for (proxy ?).

Can you give me some hints ?
Is it possible to detect those problems in my code and maybe show a message to the customers in that case ?

I can paste some parts of my code if needed.

Thank you!

Edit : I found what caused my problem. My api used an uncommon port (3088), and this port was sometimes blocked by customers network policy. I switched to the port 443 and now it runs pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a couple of options assuming you are using angulars HTTP service, as you can see the request here returns an observable, you can then subscribe to that and handle the error.

```
getConfig(): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
    return this.http.get(this.configUrl);
}

showConfig() {
  this.configService.getConfig()
  .subscribe(
    (data: Config) => this.config = { ...data }, // success path
    error => this.error = error // error path
  );
}
```

You can also retry the request like so

```
getConfig() {
  return this.http.get<Config>(this.configUrl)
   .pipe(
     retry(3), // retry a failed request up to 3 times
     catchError(this.handleError) // then handle the error
  );
}
```

You can then pop up a toast message to tell the user about the error if it occurs, here's the source material from Angular's documentation: https://angular.io/guide/http.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i will implement the route for errors in the subscribe part of my services calls.